# echo write to pp_od_clk_voltage amdgpu hang the terminal on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, drivers, gpu, hang

Trying to manipulate the frequency and voltage in amdgpu.

Any command, like:

`echo 'm 0 300 800' > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/pp_od_clk_voltage`

Just hang the termnal output. It reacts on keypresses - buttons appears on screen, but no actions
ctrl+c, ctrl+z, ctrl+x - have no effect.

System ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-53, text mode only.

Used amdgpu divers 20.30 and 20.40.
All the same effect

Video - Radeon 470:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Output of cat ppfeaturemask:

```
4294967295
```

Any advice where to dig?

Comment: Still have no ideas. Thus frozen terminal can be killed by PID. And transferred by echo values are fully accepted by the driver. But this freeze makes it impossible to write or use any script, because it stops execution. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time managed to solve my issue.

The problem is deep inside official AMDGPU drivers.

Need to use open source drivers instead, and problem disappears.

Thus "crypto-miners" don't work with opensource drivers. So need to work more on this subj. There was a suggestion somewhere on the internet, to install not all amdgpu-pro but just opencl libs from official package. But it throws an error:

```
Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
```

Maybe later I find some solution for this. But not yet.

Comment: Working deeper. Found that problem occurs after compiling and installing AMDGPU DKMS from official archive. On Ubuntu and Debian the same behavior. Maybe a bug.